# Getting wrong element when searching second time in MaterialSearchView

Tags: android, searchview, android-search

I'm using the [MaterialSearchView](https://github.com/MiguelCatalan/MaterialSearchView) library. When I search for the first time, the correct elements are returned. If I click on the first result, the correct element is selected and the `itemName` is printed out in the logcat. If I search again for another item, the correct elements are again returned but if I select any of the results, the old item is printed (from the previous search) and not the one I have selected.

This is my code:

```
materialSearchView.setOnItemClickListener((adapterView, view, position, l) -> {
    String itemName = itemNames.get(position);
    materialSearchView.closeSearch();
    Log.d(TAG, itemName);
});
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Where is `itemNames` actually defined? Also, consider opening an issue on their GitHub repository for this problem. You are more likely to get a faster response there.

Comment: Can you share the code where you are declaring it. Seems like the problem is with that rather than the clickListener as you are only getting a position attribute here rather than the list of items.

Comment: Ya, that's was it, an issue regarding the position. The position was correct but the list was filled up with old elements. Thanks anyway for that!

Comment: No problem! I have added an answer just in case someone faces the same issue in the future. If you add more details on the list, I will update the answer with more details on how the issue was fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies with `itemNames` and not the `OnItemClickListener`. The listener is only returning the position on the list of items (which seems to be correct) but the list may have not been updated.

Check the contents of the list `itemNames` and update it accordingly when a new search is made. I can't comment on how it's to be done without looking at the rest of the code.

Comment: The list should be cleared in order to get fresh data. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.